# Remove post and comment box in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I'm designing a website using WordPress. I want to know how to remove the post and comment boxes which is available by default in WordPress...and also I want to know how to add plugin's in that static page

Comment: Can you please be more specific about your requirements?

Comment: how to change the wordpress page to normal page without post and comment boxes...?

Comment: In Admin panel or public facing website?

Comment: public facing website

Comment: @user3606938 Did you get a chance to read this articles [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36123/how-to-disable-posts-and-use-pages-only](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36123/how-to-disable-posts-and-use-pages-only). [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24454/disable-wordpress-blogging-functionality-and-disable-posts](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24454/disable-wordpress-blogging-functionality-and-disable-posts). [https://github.com/tonykwon/wp-disable-posts](https://github.com/tonykwon/wp-disable-posts). many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, create page with name "Home", insert shortcode of plugin or anything you want.
Second, go to Apperance, choose Customize. At Static Front Page, tick A static page radio button, choose "Home" from dropdown list Front page. Save.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove comments yoy must select the "Screen options" in the post editor (it's an option located at top-right on the screen) and check the Comments checkbox. Then at the editor's bottom you'll find a box with a checkbox to disable comments.

If you're working in Wordpress.com you cannot add plugin's for free. This is for security reasons. You must install Worpress in your own server to do that.

Comment: I'm creating in localhost how to add plugin in it ?

Comment: You have different ways to do that: You can upload the plugin by ftp, you can add it with the left menú option "Plugins" simply as find what you like and click a button, ... Maybe the best option is first find the plugins you want to install and read the install instructions, every plugin gives you the best way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as per your comments on main question, I understand you want to remove posts and comment box on public facing page, not in WP-Admin panel.

I am giving you an overview of how you can proceed.

If you are using default TwentyThirteen thee then just remove this part from single.php

```
        <?php /* The loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
            <?php twentythirteen_post_nav(); ?>
            <?php comments_template(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

This will remove post and comments template.

However I will recommend you to use custom page templates rather :

http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

Here you'll find way to add custom page templates. There you can remove posts and comments :-)